# Building a setup in VS2015 required vs_setup.msi of VS2005

Tags: java, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2005, setup-project, ikvm

I have converted a java jar file to a dll file using IKVM.
I have created a simple C# application in VS2015 that has the converted dll as a reference to it. I had installed IKVM package using the following command:

> Install-Package IKVM -Version 8.1.5717

After the installation ended, my application has a list of IKVM dlls referenced to it.

I had created a setup project for this simple application using Visual Studio Setup project. After adding the Primary Output files and all the IKVM dlls to the setup, I am building the setup project and getting the following Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 window asking for vs_setup.msi file.

[image]

I found this file in 2 locations:

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Team Explorer - ENU\vs_setup.msi
2. "[DVD Drive]:\vss\vs_setup.msi"

When I am trying to point to those locations, I am getting the following window:

[image]

1. Why building the setup project in VS2015 required vs_setup.msi of VS2005?
2. How can I fix this issue in order to create the setup.exe file successfully?

Note: My OS is Windows 10

**Update:**
I have tried to reinstall Visual Studio 2005 SP1 but it didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it seems that not all the features from your Visual Studio were installed to your system. This isn't a bug, it's just one of the ways that some features can be installed, as "run from the DVD" or "install on demand". When it asks for the MSI file it requires the exact same MSI file, which is internally identified with ProductCode and PackageCode guids, and if they don't match the requested MSI it won't be used. From that screen shot, it's clear that the Visual Studio Premier Partner Edition disk is required, not that Team Explorer MSI file.

Visual Studio setup projects aren't part of Visual Studio 2015 - there is an installer extension that needs to be installed separately, this thing:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects

I'll repeat that your comment saying it requires vs_setup.msi is not what the message actually says. It requires the install disk, and it's possible that with the Partner Edition Visual Studio the Installer Extension is on the disk, and that's why it wants the disk. The installer extension isn't installed, but it might be on that disk. If you haven't got that disk, try installing the Installer Extension from that link above.

Comment: thank you for your recommendations. I've tried to point to the disc from where I have installed VS2005 but it doesn't help. I've also tried to install the link you suggested but still did not helped.